# Disabling tensorflow os level warning.

Tags: python, tensorflow

Sorry for an inappropriate question.First time installed tensor-flow.While testing if it was installed correctly getting errors/warning in tf.Session().

using python 3.5.

**Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

**Error**

```
2017-08-10 14:47:51.923532: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-10 14:47:51.924625: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-10 14:47:51.925259: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-10 14:47:51.925848: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-10 14:47:51.926445: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-10 14:47:51.926971: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-10 14:47:51.927455: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-10 14:47:51.928056: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

**Output**

```
b'Hello, tensor-flow'
```

Comment: these are not errors, only warning.

Comment: how can i remove it ?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Warning can be removed setting proper `os` level log

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='3'
import tensorflow as tf

# Also to remove permanently, add the following line to your ~/.bashrc file
export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3
```

Comment: But are there any permanent solution to it, or will have import os every time ?even the o/p seems bit fuzzy !

Comment: just add the line to your .bashrc